# undefined reference to `fcntl64' when trying make mesapy

Tags: python, mesa, sgx

I am going to start my work with mesapy, when I want to start helloworld sample, after running command make in the directory I get error undefined reference to `fcntl64' :

```
~/mesapy/sgx/examples/hello_world$ make
MAKE <=  ../../sgx_ulibc
LINK =>  app
MAKE <=  ../../sgx_tlibc_ext
/usr/local/bin/ld: ../../../pypy/goal/libpypy-c.a(implement_4.o): in function `pypy_g_ccall_fcntl__INT_INT_INT':
implement_4.c:(.text+0xe649): undefined reference to `fcntl64'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:234: enclave.so] Error 1
```

My system specification:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

does anyone know the solution?

Comment: any resolution so far?